# How can i make shadow on element like this without images?

Tags: css

[image]

How can i make shadow on element like this without images?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 [box-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) property:

```
.my-box{ box-shadow: 0 0 4px #333333; }
```